# Is there with_index method like ruby in python?

Tags: python, ruby

In particularly, I want to replace matched substrings with elements in an array. For example, I want to change `"ab.cd.def.fg"` into `12.34.def.45`, all word with only 2 characters replaced order by order in the array `["12", "34", "45"]`:

In ruby, I can do like this:

```rb
arr = %w(12 34 45)
des = "ab.cd.def.fg"
des.gsub!(/\b\w\w\b/).with_index{|x,i| arr[i].nil? ? x : arr[i]}
```

Then I got `des` replaced with `arr`. But how to do this in python? `re.sub` accept a function with only one parameter whose type is `match object`, but `match object` doesn't have index method, neither `re.sub` function provides it.

In generally, is there `sub` method which accept a function whose parameter is an iterator? Is there method to get index on iterating in python?

Comment: Maybe you could explain directly what you are trying to achieve with sample input and output, that would make your question answerable by those among us who don't know Ruby...

Comment: how would `des` look after the replacement?

Comment: does this help? [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Comment: You could instead write `des.gsub!(/\b\w\w\b/).with_index{|x,i| arr[i] || x }`,

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re.finditer` and replace the strings yourself:
(Only works, if matches are replaced by strings with the same size!)

```
import re

arr = ["12", "34", "56"]
des = "ab.cd.def.fg"

desarr = list(des)
for i, match in enumerate(re.finditer(r"\b\w\w\b", des)):
    desarr[match.span()[0]:match.span()[1]] = arr[i]

"".join(desarr) # "12.34.def.56"
```

Probably someone can find a more elegant solution.

A different, more reliable approach, using `re.sub`:

```
class Replacer:
    def __init__(self, arr):
        self.arr = arr
        self.index = -1

    def repl(self, match):
        self.index += 1
        if self.index < len(self.arr):
            return self.arr[self.index]
        else:
            return match[0]

r = Replacer(arr)
re.sub(r"\b\w\w\b", r.repl, des)
```

Comment: It splits string into char list. What efficiency if `des` is a large string such as read from a 10M text or binary file?

Comment: and, what if length of elements in `arr` is not equivalent with substring to replace, such as `arr = ["234", "23", "3486"]`？

Comment: That could both be a problem. It wasn't clear from the question, though.

Comment: I added a second possible solution to the answer.